# How could I determine the difference between the outside border and inside border of a glyph in FreeType?

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype

I'm doing some OpenGL programming in C++ and wanted to draw the outline of a glyph using FreeType 2.12.

At the moment, I'm getting the [FT_Outline struct](https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-outline_processing.html#ft_outline) and pushing the array of points into a vector of floats, then drawing a line using the points. The issue is that storing only the points leads to lines that connect the inside borders of a glyph to the outside borders of a glyph.

For example, when drawing "d":

[image: a line connects the inner border of "d" to the outer border.]

I'd like to draw the inner portion of the glyph and the outer portion of the glyph separately, but I don't know when the points defining the outer border stop and the points defining the inner border begin, or vice versa.

I'm aware that FreeType has [the ability to distinguish between inside borders and outside borders](https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-glyph_stroker.html#ft_outline_getinsideborder), which returns an [FT_StrokerBorder](https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-glyph_stroker.html#ft_strokerborder) but I'm not sure how to use it to get the index where the inside border begins and the outside border ends.

Is there a way to get the index of the point that separates the inside and outside borders?

Comment: The example makes it much clearer that you mean the topology. The FT documentation doesn't really explain that very well.